# Foselasticabundle : How to add a script to FunctionScore in a query ? Elastica

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I need to add a functionScore to my query to define a specific relevance for my results.

Here is my working code :

```
 $query      = new BoolQuery();
 $filters    = new BoolFilter();

 $query = new Query\Term();

 $query->setTerm($field, $value);
 $query->addMust($query);
 $query = new Query\Filtered($query, $filters);

 $finalQuery = new Query($query);
 $finalQuery->addSort(array('maxCapacity' => array('order' => 'asc')));

 $type->search($finalQuery, array('from' => (int)$from, 'size' => (int)$limit));
```

And I need to add something like this to my query, but I can't figure out how to do :

```
 $script = new Script("doc['pricehour'].value * 0.2 + doc['priceDay'].value * 0.4");
 $score = new \Elastica\Query\FunctionScore();
 $score->addScriptScoreFunction($script);
```

Am I in the right direction?

P.S. My _score in the result set is null since I used the sort, any idea on how to reactivated it with FosElasticaBundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@GregOs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755413)'s question post.

> I finally found the solution. Everything in Elastica is about wrapping the queries.
>
> I now can perform a FunctionScore query like this :
>
> ```
> $scoreQuery = new Query\FunctionScore($query);
> $finalQuery = new Query($scoreQuery);
>
> $script = new Script("doc['pricehour'].value * 0.2 + doc> ['priceDay'].value * 0.4");
> $scoreQuery->addScriptScoreFunction($script);
>
> $type->search($finalQuery, array('from' => (int)$from, 'size' => (int)$limit));
>
> And I perform either the score, either the sort.
> ```